# Shell Script to Validate Filename

Tags: unix, sh, data-warehouse, informatica

I have a requirement of creating a script to validate the filename. 
There will be two files in the source from where Informatica job start picking up these files. One will be 'In progress File (Current day : Sysdate)' and the other will be Completed/ Closed File (previous day : i.e. with a file name aligned to Sysdate -1). Now ETL has to pick up all the files except In progress File ( File date is less than Sysdate). 
Assuming current day is “22/06/2015” – the following is the list of files that ETL can expect to see in the source folder

filename_22/06/2015_ready.csv – this file should be ignored 
filename_21/06/2015_ready.csv – this file should be processed by ETL

Please help me how I can write the shell script to fulfill this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `find` instead of regular expressions reading the filename.

Commands like these should give you the files written the day before:

```
# print a list of all files older than one day expressed in minutes (60*24) 
find . -type f -mmin +$((60*24)) -exec ls -halt {} +
# print a list of all files older than one day, expressed in multiple of 86400 seconds
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec ls -halt {} +
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you your Reply. I tried 'find . -type f -mmin +1 -exec ls {} +' which is giving me all the files inculding today's file. In the expression 'find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec ls -halt {} +' I am getting error of no such file or directory.

Comment: mmh, ok: from `man find`:  *When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last  accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.* . This means that you should use `-mmin +$((60*24))` for last day files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
    path="PathToYourFiles";
    `cd $path`
    for i in `ls *.csv`;
     do
            filedate=`echo "$i" |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}'`
            #echo "Filedate => $filedate";
            today=`date '+%d%m%Y'`;
            yesterday=`date -d "1 day ago" '+%d%m%Y'`;
            case  "$filedate" in
                $today )
                    echo "ignoring file its in progres";
                    ;;
                $yesterday )
                    echo "proces the file";
                    ;;
                *)
                    echo "invalid file to process";
                    ##send it to ETL
                    ;;

                    #echo "today => $today ,yesterday => $yesterday"
            esac
    done
```

use this script and do changes as per your requirement i have provided the comments and debugging code also.

In above code add the command to send yesterdays file to ETL in $yesterday case.
I have considered date in ddmmyyy format please do change the filename accordingly.